# What is the maximum number of inversion an Array A of size n can have?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, discrete-mathematics, recurrence

We have an array A[1...n]. In inversion is when i < j but A[i] > A[j].
I want a way to describe the maximum number of inversion that an array A of length n can have (consider that the starting index is 1 not 0).

I tried to find a pattern but can't seem to come up with a generalized formula for n.

```
at n=3 we have 3 possible inversions
at n=4 we have 7 possible inversions 
at n=5 we have 10 possible inversions 
at n=6 we have 15 possible inversions (10 + 5)
at n=7 we have 21 possible inversions (15 + 6)
at n=8 we have 28 possible inversions (21 + 7)
```

There seems to be a recurrence `nb inversions for n = nb inversion for n-1 + (n-1)` but it does not seem to hold for `n=3,4,5`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maximum number of inversions is reached for array sorted in reversed order.

Such array contains

```
(n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) +.. + 1 = n*(n-1)/2
```

inversions (formula for arithmetic progression, so-called `triangular numbers`)

Note that `at n=4 we have 7` is mistake - only 6.